# Facebook C# SDK Post to page wall Issue

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk

For a good period of time our asp.net 4.0 application has been running fine and posting to our facebook page wall as expected, for over a year infact. Four weeks ago it stopped throwing an OAuthException and I've just begun to investigate. The error we get is:

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred
```

So what changed - In short I have no idea but have investigated and managed to post through the application, with one key piece of information missing - the Link which is the important part of the post.

```
var args = new Dictionary<String, object>();
args["message"] = "test message";
args["link"] = "http://www.google.co.uk";
args["picture"] = "http://mylogo";

Facebook.FacebookClient app = new Facebook.FacebookClient(app_token);

var result = app.Post("/ID/feed", args);

return result.ToString().Replace("\"", "").Replace("{id:", "").Replace("}", "");
```

This is the original code, which worked perfect and suddenly stopped.

If i comment out `args["link"] = "http://www.google.co.uk";` the problem is resolved and the exception is no longer thrown and the item is posted to the wall minus the hyperling. It is most bizarre and more over quite frustrating trying to diagnose.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Comment: Are you really trying this with google.co.uk, or a different URL? If it's a different URL, try sharing it within the composer on facebook.com, and check whether there are any anti-spam filters blocking it from being shared.

Comment: No i wasn't trying this with google, just an example. As it goes it was another change made on facebooks side that caused an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So still unsure as what happened but switched it to using an expandoobject and adding the following

```
parameters.actions = new
            {
                name = "title",
                link = "http://website.com",
            };
```

removing this generated the same error, so ill keep it in unless anyone else has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem
It seems that the link and the name work together
Try to add

```
args["name"] = "Google UK";
```

In my case when only the link was present Facebook tried to get an image from the site.

However name without link was not working at all

Cheers